# how to set preloader in magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2

For Magento 2.2.5 how to set preloader for all pages. Is there any default preloader? we already tried with custom preloader but jquery not working correctly. Themes we used BizKick Theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a module for preloader. You need to follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create file **module.xml** under:

> /app/code/STech/Preloader/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Preloader" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

**Step 2:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> /app/code/STech/Preloader/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Preloader',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 3:**
Create **default.xml** under:

> /app/code/STech/Preloader/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="STech_Preloader::js/preloader.js"/>
        <css src="STech_Preloader::css/preloader.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="container.preloader" as="preloader" template="STech_Preloader::preloader.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **preloader.phtml** under:

> /app/code/STech/Preloader/view/frontend/templates/preloader.phtml

with below content:

```
<div class="loader-wrapper">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="loading">
            <div class="bounceball"></div>
            <div class="text"><?= __('Now Loading') ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step 5:**
Create **preloader.css** under:

> /app/code/STech/Preloader/view/frontend/web/css/preloader.css

with below content:

```
.loader-wrapper{position: relative; background: #fff; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.wrap {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
.text {color: #fbae17; display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;}
.bounceball { position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 37px; width: 15px;}
.bounceball:before { position: absolute; content: ''; display: block; top: 0; width: 15px; height: 15px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #fbae17; -webkit-transform-origin: 50%; transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 500ms alternate infinite ease; animation: bounce 500ms alternate infinite ease;}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {top: 30px; height: 5px; border-radius: 60px 60px 20px 20px; -webkit-transform: scaleX(2); transform: scaleX(2);}
  35% {height: 15px; border-radius: 50%; -webkit-transform: scaleX(1); transform: scaleX(1);}
  100% {top: 0;}
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {top: 30px; height: 5px; border-radius: 60px 60px 20px 20px; -webkit-transform: scaleX(2); transform: scaleX(2);}
  35% {height: 15px; border-radius: 50%; -webkit-transform: scaleX(1); transform: scaleX(1);}
  100% {top: 0;}
}
```

**Step 6:**
Create **preloader.js** under:

> /app/code/STech/Preloader/view/frontend/web/js/preloader.js

with below content:

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.loader-wrapper').hide();
    });
});
```

Thats its. Flush the cache. Run setup upgrade and other required commands and check.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Add loader in directly theme.

Follow below file path to add loader when website load. Also make loader enable disable via admin configuration.

> File path:
> magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="webloader" sortOrder="10" translate="label" >
            <label>General</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="general" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>General</label>
            <tab>webloader</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Loader::theme_config</resource>
            <group id="general" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label" type="text">
                <label>Loader Configuration</label>                
                <field id="loader_title" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label comment" type="select">
                    <label>Loader</label>
                    <frontend_model>Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Heading</frontend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="web_loader" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="20" translate="label" type="select">
                    <label>Loader Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>            
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> File path:
> magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/head.phtml

```
<?php
$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
$loaderEnableDisable = $helper->getStoreConfig('general/general/web_loader'); ?>


<?php
if($loaderEnableDisable) { ?>
    <div class="web-loader"></div>
    <style type="text/css">
    .web-loader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background-image: url(<?php echo $this->getUrl('media').'loader.gif'; ?>);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #FFF;
        background-position: center;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    require(['jquery'], function($){
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.web-loader').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
    </script>    
<?php } ?>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $scopeConfig;   
 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context       
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();        
    }    

    /**
     * @param $node
     * @param null $storeId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStoreConfig($node, $storeId = null)
    {
        if ($storeId != null) {
            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($node, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
        }
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($node, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $this->getStore()->getId());
    }
}
```

> File path: magento/pub/media/loader.gif

Add loader.gif in media folder.

[image]

Hope it help.